# Can a class contain a reference variable to itself?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

Can I have a "Person" class that has a "bestFriend" variable that is of type "Person"? If so, how do I prevent a strong reference cycle from occurring? I can declare the variable normally, but I get an error when I try declaring at as either weak or unowned.

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name:String?
    @NSManaged var age:Int?
    @NSManaged var bestFriend:Person?
}
```

If I try to declare the variable like so:

```
@NSManaged weak var bestFriend:Person? //This generates an error
```

or

```
@NSManaged unowned var bestFriend:Person? //This generates an error
```

**The Error** -"property 'bestFriend' is marked weak on class Person. Cannot generate a setter method for it."

**Update**

The class is now a subclass of NSManagedObject so I can store it using CoreData. I changed my code slightly to reflect this. The same problem persists. How can I prevent a strong reference cycle from occurring? I'm not able to declare the "bestFriend" variable as "weak" or "unowned" without generating the error I listed above.

Comment: Is your question actually about having a reference to the same type as itself or the same object as itself? Presumably you wouldn't have yourself as a best friend, (or would you)? In which case your question is about having a variable which is of the same *type*, not a variable of the same *instance* (because the person and their best friend are not the same object). Anyway you can do either, but seems you might be confusing types (classes) with instances of those types?

Comment: @sausageMachine yes I want to have a variable of the same type, not the same person.

Comment: @matt the code the causes the error is located above. it crashes in the class declaration where I declare the bestFriend variable if I try to declare it as either a "weak var" or "unowned var"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Person a subtype of NSManagedObject?  If so, yes, properties have to be strong.  And this can result in strong reference cycles.  You have to specifically break them:

> Breaking Strong References Between Objects
>
> As opposed to the default behavior between managed objects and their managed object contexts, with relationships between managed objects, each object maintains a strong reference to the object or objects to which it is related. This relationship can cause strong reference cycles which in turn can cause objects to be held in memory long past their usefulness. To ensure that reference cycles are broken, when you are finished with an object, you can use the managed object context method refreshObject:mergeChanges: to turn the managed object into a fault.

(from the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1)).

Comment: yes, they're a subtype of NSManagedObject. Thanks for the information, that's really helpful! :)